What mandates that nested types' members can have greater accessibility than the nested types
According to the 6th Edition of ECMA-335
I.8.5.3.2 Accessibility of members and nested types :

In general, a member of a type can have any one of the accessibility
rules assigned to it. There  are three exceptions, however:



A member defined by a nested type, or a nested type enclosed by a nested type, shall  not have greater accessibility than the nested
type that defines it (in the case of a  member) or the nested type
that encloses it (in the case of a nested type).


This should prevent me from writing code like this in C#
internal class EnclosingType
{
    private class NestedType
    {
        public int publicField;
    }
}

... but it doesn't. It compiles successfully into this:
.class /* 02000006 */ nested private auto ansi beforefieldinit NestedType
    extends [System.Runtime]System.Object
{
    // Fields
    .field /* 04000001 */ public int32 publicField
...

I couldn't find anything regarding this in the ECMA-335 CLI Specification Addendum.
Am I misreading the specification or is there a rationale for this that is documented somewhere officially?

I think it just means that practically it can't be more accessible from the perspective of a completely different non-nested class. If NestedType is private then there is no way for EnclosingType2 to access any of its members. It is rather ambiguous if that is the case, and could do with being reworded in the next edition.

@Charlieface can you think of an example where this exception is really relevant/enforced?

at IL level nested classes have own visibility: nested public, nested assembly, etc. This statement enforces that nested type inside another nested type cannot be public, but can be nested public. Rules also made for interpreter, which should check visibility when executing code, so rogue assembly cannot access public members inside private type

@JL0PD the nested types have their own visibility, but the members of the nested types do not. The visibility flags of nested types were there from the first version of ECMA. This third exception was added in the third version of ECMA in 2005 (Generics). Maybe Generics are somehow relevant here. Still cannot figure out why.

It is rather ambiguous, but I think it means that a member or a further nested type cannot be made more accessible than its enclosing nested type, eg making such a "grandchild" member be public won't make it more accessible than its parent type.
For example:
public class EnclosingType
{
    private class NestedType
    {
        public class NestedNestedType
        {
        }
    }
}

public class EnclosingType2
{
    private EnclosingType.NestedType.NestedNestedType _someObj;
    //  'EnclosingType.NestedType' is inaccessible due to its protection level
}


Good example, but I think the standard is just wrong here.
In the case of the 1) exception - interface members shall be public - this is enforced (or was before default implementations - test at .NET 4.5)
2) is enforced as well - C# being more restrictive than the standard
3) is NOT enforced at all by c# compiler nor ilasm - tested with ildasm/ilasm of your example.
Maybe it should have been a note...and not an exception that access modifiers do not solely determine accessibility...but that's the case with normal types - you can define public methods on internal classes.

No internal and public on top-level classes is not actually accessibility that's exported, it's just that C# uses the same keywords.

it's visibility, not accessbility.
I mean you can use public access modifier on a type that's internal.
internal class Example
{
public void PublicMethod()
{
}
}
private auto ansi beforefieldinit Example for the type
and for the method
public hidebysig
instance void PublicMethod

But that would be in respect of whether a different assembly has visibility. This clause would exclude even in the same assembly, because the enclosing type is not accessible.

It's just that the code snippet you provided should not compile if the cited exception was enforced by the compiler.

I'm trying to explain the meaning of that clause: "shall not have greater accessibility" means it can't be more accessible than its enclosing type, with respect to a type external to both of them, rather than in respect of the enclosing type itself. Perhaps if it had said "shall not have greater visibility" it might be less ambiguous.

If you think that "public" always has greater accessibility than "private", then you are misunderstood. This standard does not rank these 7 accessibility rules.
As mentioned at the beginning of the chapter you quoted, accessibility is decided based on:

The statically visible type of the member being referenced.
The type and assembly that is making the reference.

The accessibility attribute declared on a member or nested type does not represent its accessibility, it just applies the accessibility rule on the member or nested type.
The 3rd exception enforces that if a type cannot access a nested type, then that type cannot access members of the nested class. You can compare an example of C++:
class enclose {
private:
    struct nested {
        void test() { cout << "test" << endl; }
    };
public:
    static nested create() { return nested{}; }
};

// allowed
enclose::create().test();

// disallowed
enclose::nested{};


"As mentioned at the beginning of the chapter you quoted, accessibility is decided based on:" talks about visibility which is made up of accessibbility. "The accessibility attribute declared on a member or type does not represent its accessibility." then what does it represent? Either way, what eaxct case is clause 3 enforcing?

After rereading this sentence, I think what it really means is that the accessibility rules that are listed will only be applied AFTER it is statically proven that the referent has VISIBILITY of the type that holds the member. So if no visibility, the modifiers are irrelevant.
The standard does rank them - this from the 2nd exception in the text
"accessibility shall either be identical in the two definitions or the overriding
definition shall permit more access than the original definition."

From the titles of those chapters, it can be seen that visibility is for types and accessibility is for members or nested types. Therefore, accessibility is based on visibility, rather than being made up of accessibility.

The accessibility attribute just apply the accessibility rule. Accessibility is not decided by the declaration of individual members. You cannot say what the accessibility of a member is, you must say what the accessibility of a member of type is for another type.

@tinmanjk I think it true that the accessibility rules are not equivalent to accessibility. And no, the standard doesn't rank the rules, or do you think which one has greater accessibility, family-or-assembly or family-and-assembly?

@shingo from the standard.
"When a type defines a virtual method that overrides an inherited definition, the
accessibility shall either be identical in the two definitions or the overriding
definition shall permit more access than the original definition. For example, it is
possible to override an assembly virtual method with a new implementation that is
public virtual, but not with one that is family virtual. "
